# HTML: Fake img path

Tags: html, image, .htaccess, path

is it possible to fake the `<img>` path ?

For example from:

```
<img src="/uploads/middle/test.png" />
```

to:

```
<img src="/tree/images/test.png" />
```

Maybe with .htaccess?

greets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you could use aredirect in your htaccess file. 
This way you can use `<img src="/uploads/middle/test.png" />` as your path. 
And at the back of your website it redirects to `/tree/images/test.png`.

```
Redirect 301 /uploads/middle/test.png http://example.com/tree/images/test.png
```

Ofcourse you need to change `http://example.com/` to your domain.